# h5py Ignore external links when reading file

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am reading in a group from an hdf5 file, in which some of the group members are external links. I would like to be able to identify which group members are external links, and subsequently ignore them for further reading.

Example code:

```
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data = f['header']
for p in date.keys:
    (if p is an external link, detect it here!)
```

Comment: I'm using get(name, default=None, getclass=False, getlink=False) to retrieve whether it's a external link or not. If I print the type I get, for example, <class 'h5py._hl.group.ExternalLink'>. What do I put in an if statement to get the external link bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
data = f['header']
for p in date.keys:
    if bool('h5py._hl_.group.ExternalLink' in str(type(data.get(p, getlink=True))))):
        print 'External link found!'
```

Beautifully pythonic, I know... ;)